# how to connect web application deployed on elastic benstalk with mysql database instance on aws?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application deployed on elastic beanstalk. I have configured MySQL database for it. In database instance in security group i have done following changes: Type(MYSQL/Aurora), protocol(TCP), port range(3306) and source(0.0.0.0/0).
when i am trying to insert data into database using web application or fetch data from database using web application which is deployed on elastic beanstalk, i am not able to do it.
I have made changes in servlet code as mentioned on aws website but connection is not establishing between web application and RDS on aws.
I don't know where i am doing the mistake. please help me to achieve it.

Comment: what is the issue you facing ? Any logs ?

Comment: when web application is deployed on elastic beanstalk it is not connecting to aws RDS instance. But when it is running on localhost then it is connecting to aws RDS instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to connect the mysql instance from web application:

- Copy the Endpoint from the RDS instance which will be the hostname
  for your mysql database.
- SSH into the EC2-Instance
- Use mysql to connect to the RDS instance using the following command:

  mysql -u username -p -h HOSTNAME

where HOSTNAME is the endpoint of your RDS instance.

Also, you have mentioned you have inbound all the traffic in the VPC security groups. This is not the recommended way to connect to a database.Database should always be secured from the outside world.
You have to explicitly mention the source from where the connections will be coming.

Eg:

   Type                Protocol   Port Range      Source  

MySQL/Aurora     TCP       3306         security group id of the application

Comment: I have already tried this. It's not working. What all changes i'll have to do in my java servlet code to connect to RDS instance?